# Наложение картинок друг на друга и манипуляции с ними

Tags: android, изображения, графика, graphics, обработка-изображений

Как и с помощью каких библиотек можно сделать некий редактор графики в Android Приложении, необходимо только: Наложить 1 картинку поверх другой, возможность ее переместить и повернуть.

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например с помощью библиотеки [TurboImageProject](https://github.com/Mun0n/TurboImageProject)

Так же есть большое количество других библиотек, как [узкой направленности](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android%20image%20rotate&type=Repositories) (ротация), так и [многофункциональной обработки](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android%20image%20editor&type=) изображений.
Вы всегда можете найти то, что вам нужно, составив соответствующий запрос на Github.

Так же вы можете попробовать самостоятельно реализовать нужные вам функции. За работу с изображениями отвечает класс `Bitmap`, за трансформацию изображений - класс `Matrix`/ Получить начальные знания по этой теме (работа с изображениями)  можно из [уроков с ресурса Startandroid](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html) (начиная с 141-го урока).